# Proper dense open subset of X

Tags: general-topology

$X$ be a topological space and $U$ be a **proper dense open** subset of $X$.
Then pick the correct statement from the following:

1. If $X$ is connected then $U$ is connected.
2. If $X$ is compact then $U$ is compact.
3. If $X\setminus U$ is compact then $X$ is compact.
4. If $X$ is compact then $X\setminus U$ is compact.

Answer:

My approach is, while $U$ is open and dense subset therefore if $X$ is compact and $U$ is open then $X\setminus U$ is closed subset of X and also it is non-empty, hence $X\setminus U$ is compact.

So 
**option 4** is correct.But I don't know about other options. What to do?

Comment: I think he means the difference between sets.

Comment: yes , difference between sets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. $X=[-1,1]$ (usual topology), is connected and its subspace $U=\mathbb{R}\setminus \{0\}$ is open and dense and disconnected. False.
2. As 1., note that a compact subset of $[-1,1]$ is closed and $U$ is not.
3. As 1. $X\setminus U=\{0\}$ is compact.
4. True, as $X\setminus U$ is closed in $X$ ($U$ is open) and so compact too when $X$ is.

Answer (score 1):

1,2. $X=[-1,1]$, $U= X \setminus \{0\}$.

3.$X=(-1,1)$, $U= X \setminus \{0\}$.

Answer (score 0):

1) can't be, because if we take $X = \mathbb{R}$, $U= \mathbb{R} - \{0\}$

Then $X$ is a conected set, $U$ a open proper dense subset, but $U$ is not conected

2) can't be, because if we take $X=[0,1]$ with relative topology of $\mathbb{R}$ and $U = (0,1)$

Then $X$ is a compact set, $U$ a subset open dense of $X$ but $U$ is not a compact set.

3) can't be, because if we take $X=\mathbb{R}$ and $U = \mathbb{R} - \{0\}$

Then $X-U = \{0\}$ is a compact set, but $X$ is not compact